# How can we reconcile Leviticus 6:26-27 & Haggai 2:12?

Tags: leviticus, haggai

Leviticus 6:26-27 (KJV)

> The priest that offereth it for sin shall eat it:  in the holy place shall it be eaten, in the court of the tabernacle of the congregation.  **Whatsoever shall touch the flesh thereof shall be holy:** and when there is sprinkled of the blood thereof upon any garment, thou shalt wash that whereon it was sprinkled in the holy place.

Haggai 2:12 (KJV)

> If one bear holy flesh in the skirt of his garment, and with his skirt 
>   do touch bread, or pottage, or wine, or oil, or any meat, **shall it be holy?  And the priests answered and said, No.**

How can we understand the apparent difference between these two texts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Whatsoever shall touch **the flesh** thereof shall be holy." - Leviticus

"If one bear holy flesh in the skirt of his garment, and **with his skirt do touch...**" - Haggai

In Leviticus it's taught that the skirt (or any other container) must be thoroughly washed or destroyed after touching the holy flesh. There's no difference between these two texts - nothing in Haggai is touching the meat itself apart from the skirt of the garment, which is to be washed afterwards.

Comment: @ Steve Taylor,Is not the garment sanctified,can it not convey holiness to whatsoever it contacts?

Comment: The *skirt* of the garment cannot - it is the part which drags through the mud and feces in the streets. It will be unclean and render the meat unclean.